# R Shiny embedded video works but won't fast forward/ skip time

Tags: r, video, shiny, embed

Hi I'm using this code to embed a video:

`tags$video(id="video",src="www/explainer.mp4",type="video/mp4",width="500px",height="500px",controls="controls")`

The video shows up correctly and plays, but you can't skip time to later in the video - it only plays from start to finish. This happens in chrome and edge, but seems to work correctly in firefox - anyone know why this is and how to get around it? Will ideally need it to work in Chrome. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Didn't see the problem you are describing on my Chrome (100.0.4896)

Comment: I believe the problem only exists for files greater than 4MB. I am facing the sam problem

Comment: I've opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3982